# How do I distribute precompiled extension modules for Windows on pypi for multiple versions of Python?

Tags: python, windows, distutils, pip

I would like to distribute a precompiled C extension module for Python 2.6 and Python 2.7 for 32- and 64-bit versions of Python. How should I build and distribute that on pypi? Should I just use bdist_egg? Can I retain compatibility with pip?

I notice ordinary bdist just creates a `.zip` that does not include the Python version, although the internal folder structure does. Can this `.zip` just contain e.g. a Python26 and Python27 subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally need to run bdist_something with each version of Python you need to support. bdist_egg does indeed work with PIP afaik (you can easily test it).

The Zope Toolkit has several binary distributions for Windows, and it's using binary eggs: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface

Comment: Hmm, it still downloads the tarball and compiles on mine. Will have to try again with a machine that does not have the compiler installed.

Comment: Do they have the same versions? Both pip and easy_install will typically prefer the eggs if they are available.

Comment: The package is called cryptacular.

Comment: @joeforker: OK, I just install Python on my mums Windows machine, and congratulations! You have found a situation where easy_install works better than pip. :) I suggest you file a bug against pip, because IMO that should work.