# How to distribute a cpython extension that loads into multiple versions of python?

Tags: python, cpython

We are creating a software extension for multiple 3d applications as a plugin. For platforms that we cannot explicitly write a plugin for, we're working on a cpython extension that would allow customers to get our functionality into their favourite 3d application, as long as it supports Python. The idea would be to use our existing installers to install the python extensions in a way that makes it automatically accessible in all kinds of 3d applications with embedded python support as well as any regular python installation.

Installing our extension into the systems python isn't really an option, because lots of applications (especially on windows) come with their own python installation. What worked like a charm so far was installing into a common location and adding that to PYTHONPATH. The nice thing about that is that all python instances, whether embedded or not, seem to check that path and load our extension. The downside of that is that all python instances, regardless of which version they are, check that path. So if I put a python 2.7 extension there, it will load nicely into all instaces of python 2.7, but all other versions will complain.

Is there a way of distributing a python extension so that I can keep the nice properties that the PYTHONPATH way has, but provide implementations for several python versions?

Since with pure python modules without binary extensions it seems to be possible to react to versions, I thought about making use of that. The idea would be to actually load a regular python module that queries the version and picks the correct binary to import. The only way of doing that seems to be, to check for the version, add the path to the appropriate extension to the search path, import it (under a different name I guess) and for every function in the extension write an identical python function that just patches the function call through to the extension. This seems a bit wasteful, though.

I did notice the question "[How do I distribute precompiled extension modules for Windows on pypi for multiple versions of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618918/)", but it seems to be pretty pypi specific.

Any insight into what a good strategy might be would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured it out right after I posted the question. Let's say I want to have a module called "mymodule". I pointed PYTHONPATH to a folder location. Inside that location I created a folder "mymodule" that contains an __init__.py to indicate this is a module. Then I added subfolders called python27 and python33 which contains the binary extension. The modules have been renamed to "_mymodule.pyd" to avoid name clashes. The __init__.py then checks the version, adds the path to the binary extension to the search path and imports the content of the extensions into the mymodule namespace like this:

```
import sys, os

if sys.version_info.major == 2 and sys.version_info.minor == 7:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "python27"))
    from _mymodule import *
elif sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor == 3:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "python33"))
    from _mymodule import *
else:
    raise ImportError("mymodule module found but doesn't support the current python version (" + str(sys.version_info.major) + "." + str(sys.version_info.minor) + ")")
```